# How to add a new Row in Datatables after a successful submission of form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Can anyone tell me how to add a new row in a current datatable after a successful AJAX call.
This is my code

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/post/getUserData',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "email": window.email,
        "token": window.token
    },
    success: function(data){
        let table = $('#datatable').dataTable({
        data: data,
        "autoWidth": true,
        columns: [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'main'},
                {'data': 'shrinked'},
                {'data': 'clicks'},
                {"data": "id",
                    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                        return `<button data-id=${data} onclick="disableThis(event)" class="btn btn-warning">Disable</button>`
                    }
                },
                {"data": "id",
                    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                        return `<button data-id=${data} onclick="deleteThis(event)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
//function to add new Row inside Datatable
        $(function () {
            $('#form').bind('submit', function (event) {
                // using this page stop being refreshing
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/userShrink',
                    data: {
                        fullUrl: $('#Url').val(),
                        email: window.email,
                        token: window.token
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/post/getUserData',
                            method: 'post',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                "email": window.email,
                                "token": window.token
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                table
                                    .row.add([
                                        data.id,
                                        data.main,
                                        data.shrinked,
                                        data.clicks,
                                        `<button data-id=${data} onclick="disableThis(event)" class="btn btn-warning">Disable</button>`,
                                        `<button data-id=${data} onclick="deleteThis(event)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
                                    ])
                                    .draw()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
})
})





function deleteThis(e){
console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
}

function disableThis(e){
console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
}
```

I have tried many different methods, including `clear()` before adding new `rows` , but nothing seems to work.
I just wanna add a new row without page reload when data is returned in the very last `success` call.

P.S: Data is being successfully inserted in the DB and is also shown in Datatables as a new row when page is reloaded by the user, i just wanna do this without page reload.

Help is really appreciated, i am still stuck in this one
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add datatable in ajax success response. Something like this

```
You have to add datatable in ajax success response

$(document).ready(()=>{
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/post/getUserData',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "email": window.email,
        "token": window.token
    },
    success: function(data){
    //Add your datatable here
    table.row.add([
                    data.id,
                    data.main,
                    data.shrinked,
                    data.clicks,
                    `<button data-id=${data} onclick="disableThis(event)" class="btn btn-warning">Disable</button>`,
                    `<button data-id=${data} onclick="deleteThis(event)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
                ])
                .draw()
    }
```

Comment: You have 2 different ajax call. Both are POST, but you are submitting single form, right?

Comment: that's right, first one is to fetch the data from DB and render it in datatables (usually when a user logs in), second one is when the user submits a single input field.